# Send message when file uploaded (Plupload)

Tags: php, jquery, plupload

I have got this system implemented to my site and I need that, when someone uploads a file, **only one** message is sent to my email account. I have done this, but it sends me tens of emails when uploading big files (probably because of chunks):

**Upload.php**

```
$valor = $_REQUEST['cuadro'];
$fileName = $_REQUEST["name"];

if($valor != "tradin" || $valor != "tradsp"){
    $mensaje = "User called " .$valor. " has uploaded the file " .$fileName. " into the server";
    $mensaje = wordwrap($mensaje, 70, "\r\n");
    mail('verysecret', 'File Uploaded', $mensaje);
}

$targetDir = ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $valor;
//$targetDir = 'uploads';
$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 7 * 24 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds


// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
    @mkdir($targetDir);
}

// Get a file name
if (isset($_REQUEST["name"])) {
    $fileName = $_REQUEST["name"];
} elseif (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
} else {
    $fileName = uniqid("file_");
}

$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

// Chunking might be enabled
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;


// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
    if (!is_dir($targetDir) || !$dir = opendir($targetDir)) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // If temp file is current file proceed to the next
        if ($tmpfilePath == "{$filePath}.part") {
            continue;
        }

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge)) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}   


// Open temp file
if (!$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunks ? "ab" : "wb")) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
    if (!$in = @fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "rb")) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
} else {    
    if (!$in = @fopen("php://input", "rb")) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
}

while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
    fwrite($out, $buff);
}

@fclose($out);
@fclose($in);

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}

// Return Success JSON-RPC response
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');
```

Does anyone has got an idea to do it?

Thank you for your time,

Alberto

Answer (score 0):

Put your code for sending message after all chunks are uploaded. i.e after upload is complete. 
Most probably this is the condition which checks if every chunk is uploaded 
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
   enter code here
}